# Is there an easy way to deserialize a JsonObject consisting of similar JsonObjects that really should be a JsonArray consisting of those objects?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

OK my problem is the json that i am requesting looks like this

```
{"matthew":{...}}, {"mark":{...}}, {"luke":{...}}
```

Its is one object containing multiple objects that really should actually be an array because all these objects have an identical structure. Very silly imo. Should be an array but unfortunately i cant change this server side as it is not my api.

now if the json looked like this

```
[{"matthew":{...}}, {"mark":{...}}, {"luke":{...}}]
```

i.e. simply an array, it would be alot easier to parse right?

```
public Coin deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
    throws JsonParseException {
final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
Person person = new Person();
person.name= jsonObject.get("name").getAsString(); 
person.age= jsonObject.get("age").getAsInt(); 
return person;
}
```

This is how i interpret if the json returned is an array. But if its an object? im using rxjava retrofit and gson so it would be really sweet if theres an easy way to do this so that it looks similar to my other services that easily deserialize the json arrays.

I was thinking of just appending a square bracket to the response would make it so much easier but with retrofit and rxjava im still learning i have no idea how to do this.. Is there an easy way to interpret a jsonobject as a jsonarray if all the objects properties are identical object structures that should actually be an array?

Hope i explained it clearly!

Comment: *somehow get name* after quick look on **the gson documentation** it's obviously something like first element(there should be only one anyway) of `JsonObject.entrySet()` then `MapEntry.getKey()`

Comment: what's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Ok updated the question!